# Feedparser.parse() 'SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED'

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, rss, feedparser

I'm having this SSL issue with `feedparser` parsing an HTTPS RSS feed, I don't really know what to do as I can't find any documentation on this error when it comes to feedparser:

```
>>> import feedparser
>>> feed = feedparser.parse(rss)
>>> feed
{'feed': {}, 'bozo': 1, 'bozo_exception': URLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)'),), 'entries': []}
>>> feed["items"]
[]
>>>
```

Comment: Do you have a capture from SSL handshake ?

Comment: Is this what you need? http://i.imgur.com/1rYydb6.png

Comment: Ok it seems like your client is rejecting the server's certificate with an unknown certificate authority error What versions of python and feedparser do you have ? And did you create a self signed certificate ?

Comment: Python 2.7.9 and feedparser 5.1.3 
I didn't create any certificates, this is just straight from installing Python and Feedparser, also I should note this worked in Python 3 previously but I can no longer use Python 3 for this project

Comment: Not sure if this would help you but here is a link what i thought the problem is it also talks about a possible work around http://linux.debian.bugs.dist.narkive.com/Fa81q1tS/bug-769542-rss2email-option-for-disabling-certificate-verification, generally speaking ssl clients usually have an option to ignore the certificate verification

Comment: I think python has backported the default check for certificates to 2.7.9 too as stated here https://bugs.python.org/issue22417

Answer (score 31):

Thanks you cmidi for the answer, which was to 'monkey patch' using `ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context`

```
import feedparser
import ssl
if hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
feed = feedparser.parse(rss) #<<WORKS!!
```

Answer (score 4):

This is due to Python beginning to apply [certificate verification by default for stdlib http clients](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/).

A great explanation of the rationale of the change can be found in [this Redhat article](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2039753). There's also information regarding how to control and troubleshoot this new situation.

Both previous references explain **how to avoid certificate verification in single connections** *(which is not a solution for feedparser users)*:

- [PEP-476 - Opting out](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/#opting-out)

```
import ssl

# This restores the same behavior as before.
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
urllib.urlopen("https://no-valid-cert", context=context)
```

- [RedHat - Modifying Python programs to control certificate verification](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2039753#modifying-python-programs-to-control-certificate-verification-9)

Currently, **feedparser** users can only avoid certificate verification by **monkeypatching**, which is *highly discouraged* as it affects the whole application.

The code to change the behavior application-wide would be as follows (code taken from PEP-476):

```
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    # Legacy Python that doesn't verify HTTPS certificates by default
    pass
else:
    # Handle target environment that doesn't support HTTPS verification
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
```

[There is an issue on the feedparser tracker about this](https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser/issues/84): `How to fix SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED?`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `ca-certificates` is installed.

Ran into this issue when using `feedparser` in a docker container which was lacking it and simply installing it solved my problem.