# How to fix SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED feedparser?

Tags: python, ssl, feedparser

```
feedparser.parse('https://habrahabr.ru/rss/feed/posts/6266e7ec4301addaf92d10eb212b4546')
```

some days ago it but now it doesn't 
it is python3 feedparset

```
bozo_exception': URLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)'),)}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282797/feedparser-parse-ssl-certificate-verify-failed

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing this error

Try Using

```
import feedparser
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context=ssl._create_unverified_context

feedparser.parse(rss) #this will work
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `requests` instead:

```
import requests

feed_content = requests.get(feed_url)
feed = feedparser.parse(feed_content.text)
```

although I don't know why requests has success when it verifies the certificate and feedparser doesn't.