# feedparser for reddit returning empty

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

I am trying to use feedparser with `python` to fetch the most recent posts from a sub_reddit.

I have the code below but it is not returning anything when I run it.

```
import feedparser

feed = feedparser.parse("http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/new/.rss")
#feed = feedparser.parse("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/england/london/rss.xml")

feed_entries = feed.entries

for entry in feed.entries:
    article_title = entry.title
    article_link = entry.link
    article_published_at = entry.published # Unicode string
    article_published_at_parsed = entry.published_parsed # Time object
    print (article_title)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is related to a previous entry regarding an SSL issue with feedparser parsing an HTTPS RSS feed - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28296087/1627968

Adding the following code remedies the SSL issue:

```
import ssl
if hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

For example, in your code:

```
import feedparser
import ssl
if hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
feed = feedparser.parse("http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/new/.rss")
#feed = feedparser.parse("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/england/london/rss.xml")

feed_entries = feed.entries
for entry in feed.entries:
    article_title = entry["title"]
    article_link = entry["link"]
    print(f"{article_title}: {article_link}")
```

You might want to check the keys you use for each entry - published didn't appear to be one of them, hence me removing it in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing:

```
article_published_at = entry.published # Unicode string
article_published_at_parsed = entry.published_parsed # Time object
```

to:

```
article_published_at = entry.updated
article_updated_parsed = entry.updated_parsed
```

---

```
feed = feedparser.parse("https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/new/.rss")
for entry in feed.entries:
    article_title = entry.title
    article_link = entry.link
    article_published_at = entry.updated
    article_updated_parsed = entry.updated_parsed
    print (article_published_at)
    print (article_updated_parsed)
```

---

```
2018-12-10T22:26:20+00:00
time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=10, tm_hour=22, tm_min=26, tm_sec=20, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=344, tm_isdst=0)
...
```

---

Also make sure you use `https` protocol, just in case `feedparser` doesn't follow `http`**->**`https` redirects properly.